Help with this question about probability of n number of coin tosses
we flip a fair coin n times, we call the number of successes X and the number of failures Y, and I'm asked to prove that $$P\left(\frac{X}{Y}>1+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}\right)<\frac{5}{a^{2}}$$
this screams to me of Chebyshev's inequality but I don't know how to make sense of the random variable $\frac{X}{Y}$.
I tried plugging in $Y=n-X$ but still got nowhere.

Once you plug in $Y=n-X$ you should be able to solve for the minimum value of $X$ that satisfies the inequality as a function of $a,n$

@RossMillikan how? i just end up with $X>\frac{n\sqrt{n}+an}{2\sqrt{n}+a}$

So now you need to figure the probability that $X$ is greater than that.  I would divide through by $\sqrt 2$ to get the $\frac n2$ and try to render it as $\frac n2+$ something.  The something will be messy, but maybe you can bound it usefully.

@RossMillikan what does the n/2 gives me? according to Wolfram alpha that expression is equal to $\frac{a^{3}}{8\left(a+2\sqrt{n}\right)}-\frac{a^{2}}{8}+\frac{a\sqrt{n}}{4}+\frac{n}{2}$ i can't use Chebyshev's inequality as i don't have the absolute value

Chebyshev would count the two tails.  I believe, but haven't read about it in years, that you can take half the area it uses for one tail like you have here
